# BigDecimal stripping trailing zeros

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal value and want to remove trailing zeros up until a certain point. Here are some examples:

```
1.00000 -> 1.0
12.2    -> 12.2
19.9300 -> 19.93
```

Notice the first case we want to leave exactly 1 decimal place for when all of the decimals are zero. I would like to avoid `stripTrailingZeros()` since that can convert to scientic notation in some instances, (e.g. 1E+1)

EDIT: In this case, the scale for the BigDecimal is already set to a value greater than 5.

Comment: Do you just want to change the String representation of the BigDecimal or actually change its scale and/or precision?

Comment: The scale is already set to some high value say for example 8. But, that should ONLY apply when there are non-zero numbers. For example, 0.1234567890 should become 0.12345678

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need to use [`stripTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--) to eliminate zeroes, but you can then use [`setScale()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-) to ensure you get at least one digit after the decimal point.

```java
for (String s : new String[] { "1.00000", "12.2", "19.9300", "1e+10", "1e-10", "0" }) {
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(s);
    
    value = value.stripTrailingZeros();
    if (value.scale() < 1)
        value = value.setScale(1);
    
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

*Output*

```
1.0
12.2
19.93
10000000000.0
1E-10
0.0
```

If you don't want the `1E-10`, then you have to call [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--), because that's how the normal [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString--) will output such a small value.

Comment: @Spectric I provided links to the javadoc. I'm encouraging people to learn to actually read javadoc by not simply repeating what it says here. I know, making people read documentation, how evil of me.  

Comment: @Andreas Sorry but i forgot to mention that the scale is already higher than 1 in all of those cases I provided. Assume it might something high like 8

Comment: @user3696953 You said: *"remove trailing zeros up until a certain point"*, then specified that certain point to be 1 decimal place, and provided examples where input had scales of 5, 1, and 4, respectively. This code does exactly what you asked, and doesn't care what the original scale is. You can set the scale to 100, and it'll still remove all trailing zeroes, leaving at least one digit after the decimal point, as demonstrated by the extra examples I added.

Comment: @Andreas Your exactly right i misread your code when going through it

Comment: Took me like 30 minutes to find this awesome answer. My google-fu is getting worse.